# What is the proper way to pass options to a jquery file?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress, variables

On each page of my theme, a user has the option of adding a slider.  When they do this, they can choose several settings for the slider.  This includes things such as how long the slides will pause before changing, how long it takes for the slide to transition when it changes, and what type of transition it uses.

Now if I were to just hard code this and not let the user choose the options for the slider, the code would look like this:

```
<script>
jQuery(function(){

    jQuery('#camera_wrap_3').camera({
        height: '40%',
        thumbnails: true,
        time: 3500,
        fx: 'scrollBottom',
        transPeriod: 1200,
        autoAdvance: true,
        minHeight: '50px',
        mobileNavHover: false,
    });
});
</script>
```

What is the proper way to pass the variables that are created when the user chooses their settings to the code above?

Keep in mind that I want to be able to enqueue this file the proper way with wp_enqueue

Comment: I guess it depends a bit on what you want. Do you want it to be persistent? Bookmarkable? Reload sets back to default? There are very different implementations depending on your answer to these questions.

Comment: How is the user choosing the settings?

Comment: `mobileNavHover: false,` `<--` a semi-colon after the last property is going to give you issues later on.

Comment: @ahren: specially in IE.

Comment: The wordpress administrator would be choosing the settings.  So it would be permanent unless he changed them again.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming this is related to your question about passing variables to `wp_head` - if you want to store parameters from a plugin, Wordpress provides two (three if you are using multisite) methods depending on the scope of your parameters.

If it is specific to a page/post, then you should store the parameters in the `postmeta` table with the **Custom Fields API**. You would use `update_post_meta($post_id, $key, $data)` and fetch it with `get_post_meta($post_id, $key, $single)` where `$single` is true/false depending on if you want an array of values or just a single value - if it is something like "width" you would probably set this to `true`. More info here - http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields.

If it is applicable to the entire site, then you would store it in the **Options API** in the `options` table using `update_option($key, $data)` and retrieve it with `get_option($key, $default)` where `$default` is returned if the `$key` can't be found, otherwise it will return `false`. The last option applicable only to multisite is also part of the Options API and uses `update_site_option($key, $data)` and `get_site_option($key, $default)`. More info here - http://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API.

An excellent option for managing custom fields (and options through a premium feature) is [**Advanced Custom Fields**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/).

Assuming this is per post/page, and you are setting the values with ACF, you can then write a hook to `wp_head` to pull these fields into your Javascript. You can either put this into the `functions.php` file in your theme, or if you want it to stick around if you change themes, you can use a [**Custom Functions Plugin**](http://justinsilver.com/technology/wordpress-plugins/wordpress-plugin-custom-functions-php/).

```
// hooked to wp_head
function my_wp_head(){
    // get the current $post
    global $post;
    // get value or key "camera_time"
    $camera_time = get_post_meta($post->ID, "camera_time", true);

    // write result to javascript
    echo "<script>";
    echo "var cameraTime = {$camera_time};";
    // ... the rest of your javascript
    echo "</script>";
}
if (is_single()) // only include on single pages
    add_action( 'wp_head', 'my_wp_head' );
```

Comment: I understand that using standard page custom fields I could grab this with get_post_meta but I already have a whole framework of custom metabox blocks that are a template builder and they don't use the basic get_post_meta.  Here is a screenshot of it: http://brainbuzzmedia.com/images/simplybusiness/template.jpg.  You wouldnt happen to freelance would you?

Comment: @BRAINBUZZmedia I do, I'm traveling at the moment but feel free to send me a message: http://doublesharp.com/#contact

Answer (score 1):

you can use [extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) method for that.

```
function foo (params) {
    //default values
    var settings = $.extend({
        'someKey': { k1: 'v1' },
        'otherKey':  'oTherValue'
    }, params);
     //use it 
    if (settings.someKey.k1 == 'v1') ...
    var bar = settings.otherKey;
}
```

then just call it from your code

```
foo({someKey: {k1: 'v2'}, otherKey: 'bla' });
```

i created a simple jQuery plugin usnig this approach. [check it out](https://github.com/sagivo/jQuery-Watermark)

Comment: This works for the back end of wordpress to choose the settings and then have them permanently set?

Comment: don't know about wordpress in specific. this is a general answer about how to pass params to a function.

Comment: Hmmm which part of that example above would get the variable from the php?